# SAS EG - VB is not working without showing any error message

Tags: pdf, vbscript, sas, rtf

I have a problem in converting rtf to pdf in SAS EG using VB script. It was working under Base SAS server before.

I used the proc options to see whether nocmd is opened by default, however, it seems X command is enabled.

```
proc options option=noxcmd define value;
run;

Option Definition Information for SAS Option XCMD
Group= ENVDISPLAY
Group Description: Windows and data display information
Description: Enables the X command in SAS.
Type: The option value is of type BOOLEAN
When Can Set: Session startup (command line or config) only
Restricted: Your Site Administrator can restrict modification of this option
Optsave: PROC Optsave or command Dmoptsave will not save this option NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTIONS used (Total process time):
  real time           0.00 seconds
  cpu time            0.00 seconds

%macro vbs_pdf(rtfname=,pdfname=);
        data _null_;
             length vbscmd $ 400;
             file "temp.vbs";
             put 'Dim ObjWord';
             put 'set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")';
             put 'objWord.Visible = True';
             vbscmd='objWord.Documents.Open("'|| "&rtfname" ||'")';
             put vbscmd;
             vbscmd='objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "'||"&pdfname"||'", 17';
             put vbscmd;
             put 'objWord.ActiveDocument.Close(False)';
             put 'objWord.Application.Quit(False)';
        run;options noxwait;
        data _null_;
             command="START /WAIT CScript temp.vbs //NoLogo";
             call system(command);
             command2="DEL temp.vbs ";
             call system(command2);
        run;
    %mend;

    options noxwait;

    %vbs_pdf(rtfname=\\cifs\...\sample1.rtf,
             pdfname=\\cifs\...\sample1.pdf);
```

Below is the system I used.

```
%put &=sysscp &=syshostname &=syshostinfolong ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSHOSTINFOLONG resolves to X64_SRV16 WIN 10.0.14393  Server
```

I didn't see any X command executing within the SAS EG. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Enterprise Guide is a user interface to help you submit SAS code. Where is the SAS server you are connecting to with EG?  Is it even running on a server that is using Windows?

Comment: @Tom, thank you for your comment, I have edited my questions, pls take a look.

Comment: Are you sure the server where SAS is running actually has a copy of WORD for your script to call?

Comment: @Tom, yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help but I like to use PIPE engine to allow the SAS program to capture any operating system messages.

```
data _null_;
  length command $200;
  do command="START /WAIT CScript temp.vbs //NoLogo","DEL temp.vbs";
    put command=;
    infile cmd pipe filevar=command end=eof;
    do while (not eof);
      input;
      put _infile_;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Also make sure that the current working directory is a place where you can write the temp.vbs file.  Otherwise use a fully qualified name for the file so that it can be created in a place where you have write access.

Not sure why you are using START here? Why not just call cscript directly?  Also you can try adding redirection of the error messages to standard output to the end of the commands.

```
data _null_;
  length command $200;
  do command="cScript temp.vbs 2>&1","DEL temp.vbs 2>&1";
    put command=;
    infile cmd pipe filevar=command end=eof;
    do while (not eof);
      input;
      put _infile_;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at the edits I made in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Edits are not for replies.  Try adding 2>&1 to the end of each command just in case the operating system is sending error messages somewhere else.  Otherwise it could be that  cscript does not return any error messages when it fails.

Comment: Do you mean by updating like this? 'do command="START /WAIT CScript temp.vbs //NoLogo","DEL temp.vbs","2>&1";'

Comment: It is not a command.  Add it to the end of each command.

Comment: by adding your suggestion do command="cScript temp.vbs 2>&1","DEL temp.vbs 2>&1"; The SAS EG is keeping running forever...